# PHP-Bridge with encryption

Tags: php, wcf

I need to convert my Burning Board Bridge to [this new encryption system](https://github.com/WoltLab/WCF/blob/master/wcfsetup/install/files/lib/util/PasswordUtil.class.php#L179).

```
class Wbb3 extends Plugin {
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $db;

    public function register($username, $password, $email) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->email = $email;

        $this->db = $this->CI->load->database($this->CI->config->item('bridge'), TRUE);

        $this->process();
    }

    /**
     * Add the account
     */
    private function process() {
        $salt = $this->random_str();
        $password = $this->encryptPassword($salt);
        $now = time();
        $loginkey = $this->random_str(50);
        $ip = $this->CI->input->ip_address();

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `wcf1_user` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `accessToken`, `languageID`, `registrationDate`, `styleID`, `activationCode`, `registrationIpAddress`, `lastLostPasswordRequestTime`, `lostPasswordKey`, `newEmail`, `reactivationCode`, `oldUsername`, `lastUsernameChange`, `quitStarted`, `banned`, `banReason`, `rankID`, `userTitle`, `activityPoints`, `avatarID`, `gravatarFileExtension`, `disableAvatar`, `disableAvatarReason`, `lastActivityTime`, `profileHits`, `signature`, `signatureEnableSmilies`, `signatureEnableHtml`, `signatureEnableBBCodes`, `disableSignature`, `disableSignatureReason`, `userOnlineGroupID`) VALUES ('".$this->username."', '".$this->email."', '".$password."', '".$salt."', '2', '".time()."', '0', '0', '".$ip."', '0', '', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', null, '4', '', '0', '1', '', '0', null, '".time()."', '0', null, '1', '0', '1', '0', null, '3');");

        $this->db->select('userID');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->username);
        $res = $this->db->get('wcf1_user');
        $row = $res->row();

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `wcf1_user_to_group` (userID, groupID) VALUES ($row->userID, 3)");
    }

    private function encryptPassword($salt) {
        return $salt($salt($this->password, $salt), $salt);
    }

    private function random_str($max = 8) {
        $chars = explode(" ", range('a', 'z'));
        $rtn = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
            $rtn .= str_replace('=', '', base64_encode(md5($chars[array_rand($chars)])));
        }
        return substr(str_shuffle($rtn), 0, $max);
    }
}
```

How can I convert my code?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I solved the problem. :) Thank you!

Comment: That's great! You can post your solution as an answer here, it's helpful if anyone else comes across the same issue and finds your post.